# Problem of blurring background image (svg) while using scale on hover

Tags: html, css, svg, css-transforms

I need to zoom image in on hover and focus. On hover from .9 to 1 and on focus from 1 to 1.2.
The problem is that while scaling, the picture is blurry. No matter what size I start with, .9 or 1.
I used two solutions:

```
transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
transform: translateZ(0) scale (.9, .9);
```

But it didn't work (solution in snippet).

What am I doing wrong? Maybe there are other solutions?

```css
.button {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/FWE.svg');
  width: 28px;
  height: 36px;
  transition: transform .3s ease, background .3s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  box-shadow: none;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: scale3d(.9,.9,.9);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(.9, .9);
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}

.button:focus {
  outline: none;
  transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1.2);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
</button>
<button class="button">
</button>
```

Comment: as it's an svg, wouldn't it be better to just change the background size rather than using scale?

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pnqku2fw/1/

Comment: @Pete, good solution, but there is a trembling. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Seems a bit smoother if you animate the width of an actual image rather than a background? https://jsfiddle.net/h3ydrqmp/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant add a picture to the html-structure, only as a background-image, but thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, I used the img approach but with a pseudu-element - seems to work better: https://jsfiddle.net/dukcpa50/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the image into a pseudo element and transition the size of that element - that way you will always keep a sharp svg (seems a lot sharper than any of the other ways we discussed in the comments):

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
}

.button:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: url('https://svgshare.com/i/FWE.svg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: all .15s linear;
}

.button:hover:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.button:focus:after {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
</button>
<button class="button">
</button>
```